# PHP: unable to locate functions being used (seemingly not defined)

Tags: php, class, magic-function

I'm looking at someone else's code. There's class that calls functions like `GetSku()`, `WriteOrder($order)`, etc., but I unable to find where these are located. I've checked for …

- Other script or class inclusions: no explicit or magic functions (`__call`) defined
- `grep -rHn "n *GetSku" /path/to/codebase`: returns nothing
- Sublime's cTags: nothing found
- Original developer's knowledge base: he returned an error when I made an email request

These mysterious function are called literally like…

```
$sku = GetSku();
WriteOrder($order);
```

What could possibly define and them them work? Custom magic functions somehow? Some kind of dynamic functions? I'm scratching my head like a monkey with an iPhone.

Comment: what gives you `grep -rHn "n *GetSku" /path/to/codebase` ?

Comment: any decent ide can jump to definition, use a 
modern IDE

Comment: You should also do a phpinfo(); and find where else files could be included from. Then scan those directories as well. PHP does have a PATH environment variable for including things from external shared resources like PEAR.

Comment: Search All The Folders >Insert trendy meme image here<

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the class was included in a php file that is including some external libraries? The functions might be taken from these libraries.

Comment: I did find a PHP file that was completely obfuscated, and it's got to be the entry point for a process I wanted to modify. It highly likely includes all of the plain PHP files associated with the process. However, it looks like it's a dead end for me as far as modifying it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Could you check on the actual server if this attribute is set in php.ini?

```
auto_prepend_file
```

> Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require function, so include_path is used.
>
> The special value none disables auto-prepending.

This could be the method how non-existing functions could be loaded from external files outside the project scope.